# What should I do about `javac` command not running?

Tags: jdk

```
$ file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
/etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/etc/alternatives/javac: broken symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Oracle JDK, not OpenJDK, however use these commands to add symbolic links.

1. Add this to the path.

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/bin"
   ```
2. Create symbolic links.

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javac" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javaws" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java
   sudo update-alternatives --set javac /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javac
   sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javaws
   ```